# Defining a function (but not explicitly)

Tags: function-construction, symbolic

I have a question that must have a simple answer, but googling and searching this website did not produce an answer, so I'm asking it here.

I'm working with three variables $x, y, \theta$, and I want to tell mathematica that I have a function $f$, which is a function of $x$ and $y$ alone. I **do not** have an expression for $f$; all I want is for mathematica to produce outputs like $f_x, f_y, f_{xx}$, etc, when asked to differentiate $f$, for instance.

But I do want to get $0$ when I ask mathematica for $f_{\theta}$, since $f$ doesn't depend on $\theta$. How do I define this $f$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You mean like this? `ClearAll[f];
D[f[x, y], theta]` which gives zero, and `D[f[x, y], x]` and `D[f[x, y], {x, 2}]` etc.. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt75g.png)

Comment: @Nasser the derivatives were mainly an example of the behavior I expected, not the end goal. What I mean is to have the symbol $f$ with that behavior that I can call whenever I want. The answer below takes care of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `f` can be used for two "different" functions, one depending on three variables and the other depending on two:

```
f[x_, y_, θ_] := f[x, y]

D[f[x, y, θ], x]
```

> $f^{(1,0)}(x,y)$

```
D[f[x, y, θ], y]
```

> $f^{(0,1)}(x,y)$

```
D[f[x, y, θ], θ]
```

> $0$

Comment: Ah, I had tried something similar but without the :=. Thank you very much.